# Significance of small wine glass

Tags: analysis, the-grand-budapest-hotel

In the movie [The Grand Budapest Hotel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2278388/), why is wine served in very small glass first to Mustafa?

[image: snapshot]

Comment: ... Because Wes Anderson...

Comment: what is has to do with the small glass?

Comment: Wes Anderson's films are highly stylized, often including nonsensical crap because he thinks it's "cool"... There's no real purpose for a lot of what you see in Wes Anderson films.

Comment: In a lot of high(er) class restaurants (at least in movies and TV shows), one person (generally the man, if it's a date) will try the wine before approving it. It might be a separate glass intended for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably (technically) a [cordial glass](http://cocktails.wikia.com/wiki/Cordial_glass). These are teeny glasses that are often wine glass shaped but are designed to only hold two ounces or so, which is the serving size of most cordials.

In the film, it's being used as a tasting glass, which is usually done in the full-sized glass already on the table or brought to the table when the wine is ordered.

Here's a video that outlines the tasting process: